# I have recorded audio on client side, but getting error for unknown format when trying to load using librosa in Django views

Tags: python, django, audio-recording, audio-processing, librosa

I need to perform speech recognition in the backend using users speech without transcribing using api. I am using Django and have successfully recorded the users voice in javascript but while loading the data in views using librosa its  giving an error that the file contains data in unknown format

my ajax request

```
$.ajaxSetup({headers:{ "X-CSRFToken": token}})
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url:"{%url 'record:voice2pg'%}",
                    type:'POST',
                    contentType:false,
                    processData:false,
                    data:fd,
                    processData:false,
                    success:function(file){ 
                    alert('post successful')
                        }
                }
```

my django views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import librosa

def voice2(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request,'record3.html')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' :
            print(request.FILES)
            audio=request.FILES.get("audioData")
            print(audio)
            audiodata=librosa.load(audio)
        return render(request, 'record3.html')
```

the command prompt screen
[shows runtime error: Error opening : File contains data in an unknown format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsSur.png)

what exactly is the problem? Is it because the file is not in wav format but i tried using different audio format still the result is the same. what should i do?

Comment: when troubleshooting always strive to make the problem simpler ... to identify whether its related to the web or to python I would revert back to a command line setup ... first confirm whether the recorded audio file is good ... play the audio file from a command line audio player like ffplay, aplay, vlc or whatever ... then once thats confirmed on the command line in python import the audio file into librosa then either save the result to a new output file just to confirm your librosa read was OK ...  in troubleshooting parlance its called half splitting the problem

Comment: thanks for advice @Scott Stensland.. after trying what you said i understood that the problem exist in librosa.read because browser recording and the uploaded file workes properly. Still the error in librosa exist that the file is in unknown format